# running a script within AWS instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have a bash script that I have on an AWS instance, I am trying to get it to connect to a MongoDB database on the instance, run the JS file and pull back data from the DB into an .txt file.

the issue I am facing is that I can't get the script to connect to mongo via the mongoConnection string.

I've tried the mongoConnection string as localhost:/ on my local machine and the script works as it should.

on the AWS instance i've tried
`host:port/database -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase <db>`

from the research I've done I think I am missing a key setting for local auth but I have tried the AWS docs and it does not really point me in the right direction.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html?msclkid=d9ba49b2cf7011ec817980eaee9e6ba1

[Access Key to Replace Authentication for AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417933/access-key-to-replace-authentication-for-aws?msclkid=a3aea5d4cf7911ec8df07dd642fbd25c)

and I think this one goes in the general direction I think of what I am looking for

https://blog.gruntwork.io/a-comprehensive-guide-to-authenticating-to-aws-on-the-command-line-63656a686799

has anyone else tried this before and if so would could you point me in the right direction

Comment: Does your EC2 has a correct role attached, giving the permission to your DB?

Comment: Hi Baduker, Yes the EC2 instance has the correct role attached.